# i am not able to resolve this problem. im fetching data from api and storing in table format

Tags: reactjs

....\OneDrive\Desktop\table_react\src\components\API\Tables.js
Line 30:2:  'renderTableHeader' is not defined  no-undef
Line 34:1:  'renderTableRows' is not defined    no-undef

i tried to fetch data from api and store in table format

Comment: Please post the code of Table.js. Looks like you are trying to call a method which does not exist - or you may have a typo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.